On pythonanywhere I created a scheduled task, which after start is meant to last forever. Problem is, it creates an empty log file
My scheduled task main.py on pythonaniwhere runs once daily starting at the time I set and then lasts forever (i.e., until the next day's restart) because it contains a while True loop with a time.sleep of 60 seconds. While there are no evident issues with its execution, the problem is that if I try to access the logs (in var/log) they are empty: cat <lognumber>.log does not show anything, and if I click on the logs icon in my scheduled tasks' page, it shows a blank page.
I would like to be instructed on how to solve the abovementioned problem.
Thanks
I tried commenting out print statements in main.py to ensure they were not interfering with the log output.
I also made sure that the task was scheduled correctly, in my case by the command python3.10 <whole_path>/main.py
The problem has not been solved.

If your code does not reach the print statements, then nothing will be logged.

The script works perfectly with or without the print statements, which, if not commented out, it has no difficulty reaching.

Try adding flush=True to the print calls.  Also, keep in mind that the scheduled tasks are not meant to be run coninuously so the system will eventually kill the task after some time (depending if you use a free or a paid account).  If you need a continuous job, use Always-on task feature.

@caseneuve is correct, that your print statements should all be print("What I want to print", flush=True). Also try running it locally to see if you still have the problem, then it would be a psoblem with your code.
